# Modal dont focus when is opened

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

My modal open but I can't do anything. The screen is gray and I can't click anything and no keys work

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzXs3.png)

**html:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary m-3" (click)="abrirModal()">Filtros</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="resetaPesquisa()">Limpar Pesquisa</button>
</form>

<div class="modal fade" id="filtro">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h2 class="modal-title">Selecione os Filtros</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form [formGroup]="filtroForm" class="mx-2">
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <label class="input-group-text">Comarca</label>
            <select class="form-select" formControlName="comarca">
              <option *ngFor="let comarca of comarcas" [value]="comarca">
                {{comarca}}
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <label class="input-group-text">Vara</label>
            <select class="form-select" formControlName="vara">
              <option *ngFor="let vara of varas" [value]="vara">
                {{vara}}
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="filtrar(filtroForm.value)">Filtrar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="fecharModal()">Fechar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can't access the modal through data.bs.target and data.bs.toggle

**my component.ts:**

```
formModal!: Modal;

fecharModal() {
  this.formModal?.toggle();
}

abrirModal() {
  this.formModal = new Modal(document.getElementById('filtro')!);
  this.formModal.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, it seems that your problem is related to CSS.

Give the modal-dialog class an overlay style of z-index: 10000; or a number higher than that overlay.

```
.modal-dialog{
   z-index: 10000
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem not too long ago. In your buttons, be sure to do

```
data-bs-dismiss="modal"
```

as attributes. In the one that opens your modal, you should have your click event handler. In the button that opens the modal, you will need to have the target set to the Id of the modal. Take a look at the syntax I used in "The Button" below.

Here is some code that I used for a delete confirmation Modal:

The Button:

```
  <input
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-danger"
    value="Delete"
    [hidden]="editing"
    data-bs-toggle="modal"
    data-bs-target="#deleteConfirmation"
  />
```

The Modal:

```
  <div
    class="modal fade"
    id="deleteConfirmation"
    data-bs-backdrop="static"
    data-bs-keyboard="false"
    tabindex="-1"
    aria-labelledby="deleteConfirmationLabel"
    aria-hidden="true"
  >
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="deleteConfirmationLabel">
            Delete Recipe?
          </h5>
          <button
            type="button"
            class="btn-close"
            data-bs-dismiss="modal"
            aria-label="Close"
          ></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Are you sure you want to delete '{{ recipeTitle }}'?
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-primary"
            data-bs-dismiss="modal"
          >
            Cancel
          </button>
          <button
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-danger"
            data-bs-dismiss="modal"
            (click)="deleteRecipe()"
          >
            Delete
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```